# Recover code from Pyinstaller build and .spec file

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-3.8

I have Pyinstaller build and *pycache* folder. I also have my exe (as onedir, not onefile) and Pyinstaller .spec file.
How can I get my code out of them? I accidentally deleted it. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't be a big problem as there are some libraries to help in doing this.

1. Start off by downloading `pyinstxtractor.py` from [here](https://github.com/extremecoders-re/pyinstxtractor) and then run `pip install uncompyle6`.
2. Now open your directory and open a CLI on this location, and now copy `pyinstxtractor.py` to that directory and run the command:

   ```
   python pyinstxtractor.py executable.exe
   ```
3. Now, a folder `executable.exe_extracted` will be made on the directory, now go inside the folder and open CLI on this new location and now run the command:

   ```
   uncompyle6 executable.pyc
   ```
4. Now your code will be "decompiled" on the CLI, just copy and paste it onto a new py file.

**NOTE:**

- Also keep in mind, it is better to use the same python version as the one you created the project with for better perfomance.
- One other alternative to [`uncompyle6`](https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/) is [`decompyle3`](https://github.com/rocky/python-decompile3) which work better with codes written on python 3.7+

**UPDATE:**

If you are having troubles using `decompyle3` or `uncompyle6`, use online pyc decompilers like [PyC decompiler-love data tool](https://www.toolnb.com/tools-lang-en/pyc.html) or [Decompiler](http://www.decompiler.com/)

**Also note:** It is seen that decompilation doesn't work at times because some pyc files miss the magic headers(which manually or using codes) have to be inserted into the pyc files.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226159/discussion-on-answer-by-cool-cloud-recover-code-from-pyinstaller-build-and-spec).